# How can I add a concatinate a variable into an select-option created in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a variable that disables an `<option>` if the conditions are met. I need to add this to an existing React app that has a function that builds a select dropdown and the way I would normally do this with regular JS does not apply here. It seems fairly simple but apparently not because I am clearly missing something. Any ideas?

```
  async handleSomeChange() {
    const nearByLocations = await getCoords(this.state.zip);
    if (nearByCenters) {

      let optionStatus = 'disabled';
      let locations = [];
      for (const [index, value] of nearByLocations.entries()) {

        Object.keys(value.services).forEach(key => {
          var optionStatus = (value.services[key].serviceCode === 600 ) ? "disabled" : "disabled";
        });

        // I need to output 'disabled' as the optionStatus here:
        locations.push(<option value={value.siteID} index={index} optionStatus>{value.name}</option>)
      }
      this.setState({ locations: locations });
    }
  }
```

Comment: optionStatus does not make sense, look at the code again

Comment: I left let optionStatus = 'disabled'; in by mistake when I was testing and pasted into this question. It wasn't intentional for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default way to achieve something like this in react would be using `<option disabled={true}>`, so in your case you'll have to use.

```
<option value={value.siteID} index={index} disabled={optionStatus}>{value.name}</option>
```

In your case, there might be problems with `state` and `setState` because you are pushing `JSX` elements into an array and rendering the on the screen. The preferred way is to only push to an array an object like this

```
{ "name" : value.name, "value": value.siteID, "index": index, "optionStatus": optionStatus}
```

and then render them into the screen using

```
{locations.map(item => (
    <option value={item.value} index={item.index} disabled={item.optionStatus}>{item.name}</option>
))}
```